# Splitting comma-separated values in SQL Server (php explode like)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, explode

I have column called `Tags` in a table with comma-separated values like

```
select 'hot,sweet,wow,cool' as Tags
```

Problem is that I want to explode it with comma and show it like below

```
Tags
-----
hot
sweet
wow
cool
```

Possible?

Comment: *"I have field ... with a comma separated values"* - Why? This is all wrong. If you can, change that instead of looking for a way to split strings in T-SQL.

Comment: I was able to find *many* UDF's to handle this online. Try "sql server split udf" as the search - YMMV.

Comment: @Tomalak, the simple fact is that sometimes you can't do it the right way. You inherit terrible databases in the course of your job and have to work with them for reasons beyond your pay grade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple find and replace will do the solution.. works though it looks dirty :)

```
declare @dynamic_sql as varchar(2000)
select 
@dynamic_sql=REPLACE  ('SELECT '''+ 'hot,sweet,wow,cool' , ',' , ' '' as tags UNION  SELECT '' ' )+''' as tags'
exec(@dynamic_sql)
```

output

```
tags
 cool
 sweet 
 wow 
hot
```

Comment: The dirtier, the better!

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the defacto function is Jeff Moden's 8k CSV Splitter found [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l
;
```

Comment: Well, +1 because this ought to help someone somewhere .. another alternative is to write a CLR Table-valued function. The whole problem smells though.

Comment: Ref. http://blog.idera.com/sql-server/performance-and-monitoring/comparing-simple-efficiencies-t-sql-udf-vs-sqclr-udf-for-splitting-strings/ (although this uses a different TSQL UDF than the one presented here)